# Show/Hide IDs with multiple radio buttons and IDs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have run into a little problem. I am making a Contact Form that changes according to the Users needs.

This is my html code. My goal is to First, Hide most of the Content with the first set of raio buttons. I actually managed to get that with this Javascript:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#report').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $('#phonenumber').hide();
      $('#dateofplay').hide();
      $('#customertype').hide();
      $('#studentprices').hide();
      $('#privateprices').hide();
      $('#companyprices').hide();
      $('#customsetup').hide();
    } else {
      $('#phonenumber').show();
      $('#dateofplay').show();
      $('#customertype').show();
      $('#studentprices').show();
      $('#privateprices').show();
      $('#companyprices').show();
      $('#customsetup').show();
    }
  })
  $('#booking').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $('#phonenumber').show();
      $('#dateofplay').show();
      $('#customertype').show();
      $('#studentprices').show();
      $('#privateprices').show();
      $('#companyprices').show();
      $('#customsetup').show();
    } else {
      $('#phonenumber').hide();
      $('#dateofplay').hide();
      $('#customertype').hide();
      $('#studentprices').hide();
      $('#privateprices').hide();
      $('#companyprices').hide();
      $('#customsetup').hide();
    }
  })
  $('#student').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $('#privateprices').hide();
      $('#companyprices').hide();
    } else {
      $('#privateprices').show();
      $('#companyprices').show();
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div role="main" class="ui-content" align="center">
  <div class="ui-content-spacer">
    <h3 class="ui-bar ui-bar-a ui-corner-all ui-content-spacer">
      Booking Form
    </h3>
    <div class="ui-body ui-body-a ui-corner-all ui-content-spacer">
      <form method="post" action="">
        <div class="form-field-contain">
          <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
            <legend>While the page is still under developement please define your inquiry: </legend>
            <input type="radio" name="settings" id="report" value="report">
            <label for="report">Bug Report</label>
            <input type="radio" name="settings" id="booking" value="booking" checked="checked">
            <label for="booking">Booking</label>
          </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div class="form-field-contain ui-field-contain">
          <label for="firstname">First Name:</label>
          <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" value="" placeholder="First Name...">
        </div>
        <div class="form-field-contain ui-field-contain">
          <label for="lastname">Last Name:</label>
          <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" value="" placeholder="Last Name...">
        </div>
        <div class="form-field-contain ui-field-contain">
          <label for="email">E-Mail</label>
          <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="" placeholder="E-Mail...">
        </div>
        <div class="form-field-contain ui-field-contain" id="phonenumber">
          <label for="tel">Phone:</label>
          <input type="tel" name="tel" id="tel" value="" placeholder="Phone #...">
        </div>
        <div class="form-field-contain ui-field-contain" id="dateofplay">
          <label for="date">Date of event:</label>
          <input type="date" name="date" id="date" value="" placeholder="Please choose a Date">
        </div>
        <div class="form-field-contain ui-field-contain">
          <label for="message">Write a quick Message:</label>
          <textarea cols="40" rows="8" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Your Message here..."></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-field-contain" id="customertype">
          <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
            <label><input type="radio" name="customertype" id="student" value="Student/Apprentice">Stundent/Apprentice</label>
            <label><input type="radio" name="customertype" id="private" value="private" checked="checked">Private</label>
            <label><input type="radio" name="customertype" id="company" value="company">Company</label>
          </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div class="form-field-contain" id="studentprices">
          <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
            <label><input type="radio" name="studentprice" id="studentminimal" value="studentminimal" checked="checked">Minimal</label>
            <label><input type="radio" name="studentprice" id="studentsoundonly" value="studentsoundonly">Sound Only</label>
            <label><input type="radio" name="studentprice" id="studentsoundandlight" value="studentsoundandlight">Sound and Light</label>
            <label><input type="radio" name="studentprice" id="studentpartypackage" value="studentpartypackage">Total Party Package</label>
            <label><input type="radio" name="studentprice" id="studentcustom" value="0">Custom</label>
          </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div class="form-field-contain" id="privateprices">
          <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
            <label><input type="radio" name="privateprice" id="minimal" value="150" checked="checked">Minimal</label>
            <label><input type="radio" name="privateprice" id="soundonly" value="200">Sound Only</label>
            <label><input type="radio" name="privateprice" id="soundandlight" value="300">Sound and Light</label>
            <label><input type="radio" name="privateprice" id="partypackage" value="400">Total Party Package</label>
            <label><input type="radio" name="privateprice" id="custom" value="0">Custom</label>
          </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div class="form-field-contain" id="companyprices">
          <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
            <label><input type="radio" name="companyprice" id="companyminimal" value="200" checked="checked">Minimal</label>
            <label><input type="radio" name="companyprice" id="companysoundonly" value="300">Sound Only</label>
            <label><input type="radio" name="companyprice" id="companysoundandlight" value="400">Sound and Light</label>
            <label><input type="radio" name="companyprice" id="companypartypackage" value="500">Total Party Package</label>
            <label><input type="radio" name="companyprice" id="companycustom" value="0">Custom</label>
          </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div class="form-field-contain" id="customsetup">
          <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" id="customsetup">
            <legend>Custom choices:</legend>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="speakers" id="speakers" value="">Speakers</label>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="subwoofer" id="subwoofer" value="">Subwoofer</label>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="lighting" id="lighting" value="">Lighting</label>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="strobe" id="strobe" value="">Strobelight</label>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="fog" id="fog" value="">Fogmachine</label>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="table" id="table" value="">Table</label>
          </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div class="form-field-contain">
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" data-inline="true">
          <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" data-inline="true">
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I think the problem is that, because the first show/hide function is hiding/showing the ID's it overrides any following function. I can't wrap my head around how I can continue the code so the radio buttons that are not required are hidden.

So if,

#student is selected, #privateprices and #companyprices choices are hidden

#private is selected, #studentprices and #companyprices choices are hidden

#company is selected, #studentprices and #privateprices choices are hidden

Is it even possible or is there a easier more effective method of achieving this? Especially when I start creating the php for the form? Thanks in advance

EDIT: The last piece of code in the Javascript is my attempt hide the first set of radiobuttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check which radio button is selected in page loading and show / hide the panels. Please see working fiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/ranjitsachin/Leav016c/2/

```
$('#student').on('click', function() {
     if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $("#studentprices").show();
        $('#privateprices, #companyprices').hide();
   }
});
$('#private').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $("#privateprices").show();
        $('#studentprices, #companyprices').hide();
    }
});
 $('#company').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $("#companyprices").show();
       $('#studentprices, #privateprices').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried your method. It works fine in jsfiddle but then when implemented into my form with the bootstrap css it seems to interfere with the jquerymobile framework. It ends up changing the radio button layout. And  only the first radio buttons acutally work.

Comment: Please can you share your js fiddle.

Comment: I am very confused. The code works in the JSFiddle. When implemented into my page it doesn't work. Here is my JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/mullern/3jgocw2c/1/

Comment: Your fiddle is working fine.. Hope you solved the problem.

Comment: I am terribly sorry for the hassel. To find the Problem i decided to Piece together my page into one html file rather than split into php files with the include function. Turns out there must be a problem with the page itselft which I cannot identify. I inserted my entire page into a JSFiddle. Maybe you or Someone else is able to find the error.
https://jsfiddle.net/mullern/Lf9jL50f/1/

Comment: I found it!! It turns out in the Package info I have identical ID's for the Popups, to the ones i tried to hide. This is what was causing problems. I am very sorry for the inconvenience. Thank you very much for helping me with code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working pen on how I would do it. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jBryOa

In this pen, i added the classes of `report-group` and `booking-group` to the respective `div`s, added a class of `hide-group` to the css with a setting of `display: none;` and then add and remove the class `hide-group` based on which radio button is checked. I also added the class `hide-group` in the html to the div's that need to be initially hidden.

I did not add the groups to every div. just enough to show you what you need to do.